# Python 3.4 reading from CSV formats

Tags: python, csv, numpy, formats

OK So i have this code in Python that Im importing from a csv file the problem is that there are columns in that csv file that aren't basic numbers. There is one column that is text in the format "INT, EXT" and there is a column that is in o'clock format from "0:00 to 11:59" format. I have a third column as a normal number distance in "00.00" format.

My question is how do I go about plotting distance vs o'clock and then basing whether one is INT or EXT changing the colors of the dots for the scatterplot.

My first problem is having how to make the program read oclock format. and text formats from a csv.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance

Here is a sample of the CSV im trying to import

```
ML  INT  .10  534.15  0:00
ML  EXT  .25  654.23  3:00
ML  INT  .35  743.12  6:30
```

I want to plot the 4th column as the x axis and the 5th column as the y axis
I also want to color code the scatter plot dots red or blue depending if one is INT or EXT

Here is a sample of the code i have so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')

a,b,c,d = np.loadtxt('numbers.csv',
                unpack = True,
                delimiter = ',')



plt.scatter(a,b)




plt.title('Charts')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.xlabel('X Axis')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your csv file?

Comment: Let me know if I'm not understanding you, but I think the crux of your issue is converting a time of day to something that matplotlib can scatter. It seems like converting that to seconds since midnight would do the trick. MrE's suggestion to include some data is a good one though if you'd like useful help.

Comment: ok i added some stuff on there hopefully it makes it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading in from your example csv using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t', header=None)
print data
```

prints:

```
    0    1     2       3     4
0  ML  INT  0.10  534.15  0:00
1  ML  EXT  0.25  654.23  3:00
2  ML  INT  0.35  743.12  6:30
```

Then separate the 'INT' from the 'EXT':

```
ints = data[data[1]=='INT']
exts = data[data[1]=='EXT']
```

change them to datetime and grab the distances:

```
int_times = [datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')) for t in ints[4]]
ext_times = [datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')) for t in exts[4]]
int_dist = [d for d in ints[3]]
ext_dist = [d for d in exts[3]]
```

then plot a scatter plot for 'INT' and 'EXT' each:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(int_dist, int_times, c='orange', s=150)
ax.scatter(ext_dist, ext_times, c='black', s=150)
plt.legend(['INT', 'EXT'], loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Adding code to answer a question in the comments regarding how to change the time to 12 hour format (ranging from 0:00 to 11:59) and strip the seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
ints = data[data[1]=='INT']
exts = data[data[1]=='EXT']
INT_index = data[data[1]=='INT'].index
EXT_index = data[data[1]=='EXT'].index
time = [t for t in data[4]]
int_dist = [d for d in ints[3]]
ext_dist = [d for d in exts[3]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(int_dist, INT_index, c='orange', s=150)
ax.scatter(ext_dist, EXT_index, c='black', s=150)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(data[4])))
ax.set_yticklabels(time)
plt.legend(['INT', 'EXT'], loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how do i make the time format into 12hr o clock format to read 0:00, 1:00 etc. wthout having 00:00:00 excess :00 at the end of it?

Comment: @Archimedes I can edit my answer to include 12hr clock and to strip excess zeros off. Also, if you feel it answers (both) of your questions, you can click the check to accept my answer.

Comment: one last question. I need the y axis to be fixed length ranging from 0:00 to 12:00 how do i go about ding that?

Comment: 0:00 at the bottom and 12:00 all the way at the top

Comment: the data i have stops always at 11:59 but for the sake of image purposes i need my graph to have 0:00 to 12:00 on the axis with tick marks at every 1 hr. So basically the graph you've shown me is correct I just need to be able to put 0:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00 etc in increments of 1 hr all the way up to 12 as the y axis tick marks and have the data graph accordingly.

Comment: my question still stands, your graph still only places 0:00, 3:00 and 6:30 on the y axis. I need it to always show 0:00 to 12:00 in 1 hr increments regardless of what data I have and then plot my data accordingly. I'm sorry if i'm not clear. having 0:00 to 12:00 on the y axis will always be a constant. only the x axis will change depending on the data

Comment: So if your full dataset fully ranges 0:00 through 11:59 then the idea with the edit is that the y-axis will update accordingly.  If you just wanted to have a static y-axis showing '0:00','1:00', ..., '12:00' (which has no knowledge of your data or how to interpolate) then I don't know how to make that work.

Comment: @Archimedes I added another answer below.  If your data is similar to the fake data I made it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked another answer to this, but will leave the original as I believe it's still good, just not exactly answering your particular question.

I also generated a few more rows of data to make the problem, at least on my end, a bit more meaningful.

What solved this for me was generating a 5th column (in code, not the csv) which is the number of minutes corresponding to a particular o'clock time, i.e. 11:59 maps to 719 min.  Using pandas I inserted this new column into the dataframe.  I could then place string ticklabels for every hour ('0:00', '1:00', etc.) at every 60 min.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('Workbook2.csv', header=None)
print data
```

Prints my faked data:

```
    0    1     2       3      4
0  ML  INT  0.10  534.15   0:00
1  ML  EXT  0.25  654.23   3:00
2  ML  INT  0.30  743.12   6:30
3  ML  EXT  0.35  744.20   4:30
4  ML  INT  0.45  811.47   7:00
5  ML  EXT  0.55  777.90   5:45
6  ML  INT  0.66  854.70   7:54
7  ML  EXT  0.74  798.40   6:55
8  ML  INT  0.87  947.30  11:59
```

Now make a function to convert o'clock to minutes:

```
def convert_to_min(o_clock):
    h, m = o_clock.split(':')
    return int(h) * 60 + int(m)
# using this function create a list times in minutes for each time in col 4
min_col = [convert_to_min(t) for t in data[4]]
data[5] = min_col  # inserts this list as a new column '5'
print data
```

Our new data:

```
    0    1     2       3      4    5
0  ML  INT  0.10  534.15   0:00    0
1  ML  EXT  0.25  654.23   3:00  180
2  ML  INT  0.30  743.12   6:30  390
3  ML  EXT  0.35  744.20   4:30  270
4  ML  INT  0.45  811.47   7:00  420
5  ML  EXT  0.55  777.90   5:45  345
6  ML  INT  0.66  854.70   7:54  474
7  ML  EXT  0.74  798.40   6:55  415
8  ML  INT  0.87  947.30  11:59  719
```

Now build the x and y axis data, the ticklabels, and the tick locations:

```
INTs = data[data[1]=='INT']
EXTs = data[data[1]=='EXT']

int_dist = INTs[3]  # x-axis data for INT
ext_dist = EXTs[3]

# plotting time as minutes in range [0 720]
int_time = INTs[5]  # y-axis data for INT
ext_time = EXTs[5]

time = ['0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', 
        '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00']
# this will place the strings above at every 60 min
tick_location = [t*60 for t in range(13)]
```

Now plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(int_dist, int_time, c='orange', s=150)
ax.scatter(ext_dist, ext_time, c='black', s=150)
ax.set_yticks(tick_location)
ax.set_yticklabels(time)
plt.legend(['INT', 'EXT'], loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('Seems to work...')
plt.show()
```

[image]